# Show certain page on repeat visits based on user selection

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, cookies, local-storage

I have a modal that launches on page load and asks the users a few questions (this is to qualify them because our product is suited to many industries. Once they choose an option from the modal, they are brought to a page that is targeted to their industry).  **This is a web page and not an app.

I'm a beginner so any help is welcomed. Is it possible to have their choice remembered? So that if they were to return to the web page, it would go straight to that targeted page rather than challenge them with the pop up every time? I assume this can be done with cookies but I'm not sure where to begin with that.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">What Best Describes You?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please choose which best describes you so you can see content relevant to your industry.</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spacing">
                <li>I am a</li>
                <li>I am a</li>
                 <li>I am a</li>
                 <li>I am a</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store user entered data in local storage and until user clears it, it will always be available to you. so on page load you check for the data from local storage if it's available use that else prompt user to enter the details.

to save data - `localStorage.setItem('key', val);`
in your case you are trying to remember multiple values so better create an object and save the same.

for exmpale -

```
    var userDataOnLoad = localStorage.getItem('userData');

    // check if userDataOnLoad defined    
    if(userDataOnLoad) {

       // take the values out of the object
       var username = userDataOnLoad.userName,
           industry = userDataOnLoad.industry;

    } else {

      // prompt user to enter data and save it here in local storage
      var data = {};
      data.userName = 'abc';
      data.industry = 'information technology';
      // other details.

     // save the entire user data object to local storage
     localStorage.setItem('userData', data);
    }
```